# TestFlight What's the difference between both status Approved and Ready to Submit?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I used to upload a build to the appstoreconnect almost every week for testing before submitting the final version to the appstore.
I have noticed that app status sometimes is ***approved***  other time it was ***Ready to Submit***

> What's the difference between both status ***Approved*** and ***Ready to Submit*** both haven't been submitted to the appstore yet.
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

**Approved** - Your app has passed the Beta review. Once Approved, your External testers can test the app via TestFlight.
**Ready to Submit** - Your build can be distributed to internal testers, or can be submitted to Beta App Review for external testing or to App Review for release on the App Store.

Comment: **Ready to Submit means** Your build can be distributed to internal testers, or can be submitted to Beta App Review for external testing or to App Review for release on the App Store. See this apple reference link... https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev3d6869aff

Comment: @NiravKotecha : Check the last OR statement - or to App Review for release on the App Store.

Comment: @NiravKotecha : But yes, it makes more sense to include all.

Answer (score 0):

When application is submitted to External Testers and approved by them, Test Flight will show **"Approved"** status

When application is yet to submit to External Testers, Test Flight will show **"Ready To Submit"** status on it.

Reference:

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev18557d60e

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev3d6869aff