# App Store Approved status, what to do next?

Tags: ios, flutter, release

I want to publish my app, I see that my build version in TestFLight have status Approved, I do not know what next action I need to do in order to publish my App.

From that link: [TestFlight What's the difference between both status Approved and Ready to Submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018667/testflight-whats-the-difference-between-both-status-approved-and-ready-to-submi)

I lerned that:
"Approved - Your app has passed the Beta review. Once Approved, your External testers can test the app via TestFlight."

But I do not know what I need to do right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps to follow when publishing a new app version.

1. Upload a build to TestFlight (via XCode, command line, etc).
2. Create a new build version that is compatible with the one on TestFlight.

[image]

3. When it's on TestFlight, you can select a build in the `App Store` section. Scroll down to `Build` and click `+` to choose a build to submit. Then `Save` and `Add for Review`.

[image]

[image]

That's it. Now you need to wait for the Apple team to review your build. Generally, it will take 1-2 days. Once it's finished, you will get a notification on email or the AppStoreConnect app.

Comment: there is a problem, In App Store I can see in section Build only my old version, not the new one and I do not see + button

Comment: Alright, I edited it, you're missing the new version of the App at the start of the page. i.e., if you've created a new version 2.0.0 on AppStoreConnect, you must upload the same version via TestFlight. You can increase the build number, however, the version must be the same.

Comment: did I understand it correctly? After I uploaded my build to testFlight. I need to upload it to test flight once again? I will have 2 build's in my test flight? and then I need to go to my appStore and find build and + button? Becouse I already uploaded to testFlight and get "Approved" status

Comment: You can upload how many TF builds you want, it doesn't matter. Simply select the version you wish to publish. In case you want to upload the current TF build, you have to create a `matched` build with that TF build (step 2). And if they don't equal, well, you'll have to upload to TF again.